# How to write "pseudo" binary into file using php?

Tags: php

I have a string containing something like "01001010" and I want to write it into a file using binary. In other words, what's inside that file is not the chars 0/1,  but in binary format.
How can I make that?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php#53622

Comment: You mean you want to convert a string of the form `$bitString = '01010101...';` into binary data (`0x55`...), and then write that to a file?

Comment: Look into base_convert(), pack()

Comment: @MarcB but beware that base_convert will fail if you try and handle too many bits at once.

Comment: @therefromhere: easy enough to yank out (say) 16 chars at a time from the source string and convert them individually. As long as you convert a byte's worth of characters into bits at a time, there's no danger of running into base_convert's limits.

Comment: @MarcB agreed, but a novice would expect `base_convert($hugeString, 2, 16)` to work.  Worth pointing out the gotcha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you mean you want to convert a string of 0s and 1s (eg `$bitString = '01010101...';`) into binary data (0x55...), and then write that to a file, you need to do this in two steps.

First, convert your string of zeros and ones into binary - see [Converting string of 1s and 0s into binary value, then compress afterwards ,PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641807/converting-string-of-1s-and-0s-into-binary-value-then-compress-afterwards-php)

Note that strings in PHP can store binary data.

Then just write the output to a file, eg using `file_put_contents()`.

Comment: Nice hint anyway. Thanks. Sorry for the late reply since I almost forgot it :)